# Create column based on multiple possible tables using SQL

Tags: sql

We want to add the column `doc_val` to the `Main` table such that the value will be the `val` of the table determined by the `doc_type` at the row determined by `doc_id`.

For example, the first value of `val` will be `57` because in the first row of `Main` the `doc_type` is `'doc_a'` and the `doc_id` is `1` and the `val` of id `1` in table `A` is `57`.

```
Table Main
id | doc_type | doc_id
----------------------
1  | 'doc_a'  | 1
2  | 'doc_a'  | 2
3  | 'doc_b'  | 3
4  | 'doc_c'  | 1
5  | 'doc_c'  | 3

Table A       Table B       Table C
id | val      id | val      id | val
--------      --------      --------
1  | 57       1  | 33       1  | 55
2  | 63       2  | 26       2  | 22
3  | 72       3  | 19       3  | 54
```

The table we want is below.

```
id | doc_type | doc_id | doc_val
--------------------------------
1  | 'doc_a'  | 1      | 57
2  | 'doc_a'  | 2      | 63
3  | 'doc_b'  | 3      | 19
4  | 'doc_c'  | 1      | 55
5  | 'doc_c'  | 3      | 54
```

How can we do this with an SQL query?

Comment: Simply outer join the three tables and use `COALESCE` to show the one matching val you find in these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left join`:

```
select m.*, coalesce(a.val, b.val, c.val) as val
from main m left join
     a
     on m.doc_id = a.id and m.doc_type = 'doc_a' left join
     b
     on m.doc_id = b.id and m.doc_type = 'doc_b' left join
     c
     on m.doc_id = c.id and m.doc_type = 'doc_c';
```

An alternative method (which is probably less performant) uses `union all`:

```
select m.*, abc.val
from main left join
     ((select id, 'doc_a' as doc_type, val from a
      ) union all
      (select id, 'doc_b' as doc_type, val from b
      ) union all
      (select id, 'doc_c' as doc_type, val from c
      )
     ) abc
     on m.id = abc.id and m.doc_type = abc.doc_type;
```